# TynyVM exception working with legOS

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue, lego-mindstorms

so I'm working with legOS (the little legos robots) and basically what I'm doing is finding a solution to a maze with A* and I wanna use that to tell the robot where to move around the maze.

But the problem that I've been having is that when I try to initiate the priotiry queue it gives me this exception

```
js.tinyvm.TinyVMException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
at js.tinyvm.ClassRecord.getClassRecord(ClassRecord.java:871)
at js.tinyvm.ClassRecord.storeReferredClasses(ClassRecord.java:394)
at js.tinyvm.Binary.processClasses(Binary.java:381)
at js.tinyvm.Binary.createFromClosureOf(Binary.java:309)
at js.tinyvm.TinyVMTool.link(TinyVMTool.java:97)
at js.tinyvm.TinyVMTool.link(TinyVMTool.java:48)
at lejos.pc.tools.NXJLink.start(NXJLink.java:134)
at lejos.pc.tools.NXJLink.run(NXJLink.java:101)
at lejos.pc.tools.NXJLink.start(NXJLink.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at lejos.pc.tools.ToolStarter.startTool(ToolStarter.java:31)
at lejos.pc.tools.NXJLink.main(NXJLink.java:28)
Caused by: org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:146)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:67)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:222)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:136)
    at js.tinyvm.ClassRecord.getClassRecord(ClassRecord.java:865)
    ... 14 more
Linking the file failed with exit status 1
```

I know is with the priority queues because I've commented those lines and the program links successfully

here's where I start the queues

```
PriorityQueue<State> frontier; 
    frontier = new PriorityQueue<State>(new CostComparator());
    PriorityQueue<State> visited; 
    visited = new PriorityQueue<State>(new CostComparator());
```

Can someone tell me why this happens?

I'm using everything in 32-bit env and nothing works..

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps for future reference, the runtime library for lejOS does not support Priority queue class, only queue so I had to implement my own queue with this library.